# SQL Group By and assign highest a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ms-access

I am struggling with the SQL (mssql) to manipulate my data as i need it.  I have a table like this;

```
SOMEID, SOMEFIELD, DATE
5        True    01-01-2010
5        True    01-01-2011
5        False   05-05-2012
7        True    05-05-2011
7        False   06-07-2015
```

What I am trying to achieve is to add another column which assigns the value 1 if they are the most recent for that ID, and 0 if not. So in the above data example the new column values from top to bottom would be 0, 0, 1, 0, 1.

I know I need to group by date but am having trouble assigning the values.

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: If the question doesn’t relate to MySQL please remove that tag

Comment: Are you trying to actually _update_ your table with this most recent data, or would you be OK with just selecting out this additional column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` in SQL Server like this:

```
select *
   , case when (row_number() over (partition by SOMEID order by [Date] desc)) = 1 then 1 else 0 end seq
from 
    yourTable
order by 
    SOMEID, [Date];
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae68c/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a self join to get the highest row per group then in update query use a case statement to assign value to new column

```
update a
set a.[somecol] = case when b.[SOMEID] is null then 1 else 0 end
from demo a
left join demo b on a.[SOMEID] = b.[SOMEID]
and a.[DATE] < b.[DATE]
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c4f9e/1)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT SOMEID, SOMEFIELD, DATE 
, CASE WHEN (SELECT MAX(SubTab.Date) 
             FROM myTable SubTab 
             WHERE SubTab.SOMEID = myTable.SOMEID
            ) = myTable.DATE 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM myTable
```